# vb.net Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm coming across this error when I run my web app. The error is given only when the code is run on my web server. I can run the exact same code on my local machine and it works just fine. The the only way that I see the error when running the app on my webserver is if I press f12 when I try to run a given page. The page is trying to SFTP a file to another server, but like I said, I can run the exact same code on my local machine with no errors so I know that the code will work. There are no message or error boxes that popup. I've gone over the code over and over as well as looking at the difference of the configuration and programs that are installed on my local machine as opposed to what is on my web server. There is nothing that I see that is different. Here is the whole error message I see:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The source was
>   not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To
>   create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make
>   sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

I've found quite a few questions about this error, most of them talk about  giving access to all users in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security
```

or adding a user called `Network Service` to the above key and giving it full access or granting read permissions for the `Network Service` user to the whole `EventLog branch`. Another path I've explored is to change the identity of the app pool in IIS and then change it back. I've tried just about everything listed on SO and other places. Like I said, most of them involve writing new keys and changing permissions on keys in the registry. Another one I've tried is creating a registry key named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\#MY APP#` and then creating a string value inside it called `EventMessageFile` with the value of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll` in it. Another suggestion is to open the the app as an Administrator. That didn't work either. I could go on and on and on but for the sake of not turning this into a novel I won't, but I hope I've shown enough examples to let everyone know that I've done due diligence in trying other solutions first before asking my question. Will someone please help me out with this very frustrating error?

Comment: You seem to know the solution. Open the registry and give Full Control permissions to the EventLog for your application.

Comment: I've done that and it does not work for my situation, hence me asking for additional ideas as to how to fix this.

Comment: Let me rephrase. You don't grant permissions to "Network Service" - open the App Pool running your Application and determine which account it runs as...this is the account you need to grant full control.

Comment: @mjw thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure as to how to determine the account name that I should grant full access to. I'm running IIS 7.5. I've found items online that show how to get the identity of the pool but not the account name. Can you help me out with some instructions on how to get this?

Comment: UPDATE: I believe that I found the name of the account that is running the web app. However, when I grant it full control I still get this error. I'm wondering, is there something that has to be done before these registry changes will take effect IE: rebooting the server?

Comment: In IIS > Application Pools, right click the pool in question and choose Advanced Settings. Under Process Model you should see Identity. This is the account the application runs as. If you granted full control of the key and still get this error, I would verify that your application is logging to the key you've granted access for. Can you show the code/config for how you're writing to the event log? The exception above indicates you will need to grant access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Security`